# .htaccess rule stacking and 404 redirect

Tags: .htaccess

The user requests a PNG image, say: `http://server/myfolder/subfolder/1234.png`. If that `.png` doesn't exist, then I want to show instead a `.gif` in the same folder of the same name except for the `.gif` extension, which should exist.

Another addition is that we recently changed the directory structure so the URL that I need to check may have changed. For example, the URL above should be able to be reached by requesting either directly as `http:// server/myfolder/subfolder/1234.png`or by `http://server/oldfolder/1234.png`. The change in the directory structure can be expressed as:

```
RewriteRule oldfolder/(.*) myfolder/subfolder/$1 [L,QSA]
```

In both directories, I need to check if the file exists, and use a different image instead if necessary. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site.

It should work with your changed file structure too.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#if the file does not exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#and is in any of these folders: /myfolder/subfolder or /folder1 or /folder2 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(myfolder/subfolder|folder1|folder2)/ [NC] 
#and its a png, then try to serve the gif instead
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.png$ $1.gif [L,NC]
```

Comment: Won't that redirect all images though?  I only want it active in specific subdirectories, in any other case I want the usual 404 if the image doesn't exist.

Comment: @user1216597 It will redirect all .png images that do not exist. I have edited it to only apply to specific folders. You can change these to match the folders you want.